# 1 javascript/css issue 2 perl cgi issues

Tags: javascript, css, perl, cgi

Javascript CSS issue:

I am using a textarea box to write to a div. I get the textarea box to do this by using the following javascript:

```
<script type="text/javascript">

   function process_input(){
    document.getElementById("description").innerHTML = document.getElementById("message").value;
    return true;
   }
 </script>
```

I style the div to have white-space:pre-wrap which works in Firefox but not in IE. Does anyone know of either a css rule or some additional javascript to make the div reflect carriage returns entered in the text box to also be entered in the div?

I am working on the perl cgi script that someone else started to have the text which is using a background image sent as an ecard. Here is the perl cgi script:

```
#!/usr/local/bin/perl5

use CGI;
use GD;
use CommonSubs;
use DBI;

use dbInfo;

$q = new CGI;


$userInfo= &CommonSubs::DirInfo($userId);

$user = $ENV{'REMOTE_USER'};
$from = $q->param('from');
$to = $q->param('to');
$cc = $q->param('cc_manager');
$card = $q->param('card');
$message = $q->param('message');



my %availableCards = ("card1"  =>  "large_card_1.jpg",
      "card2"  =>  "large_card_2.jpg",
      "card3"  =>  "large_card_3.jpg",
      "card4"  =>  "large_card_4.jpg",
      "card5"  =>  "large_card_5.jpg",
      "card6"  =>  "large_card_6.jpg",
      "card7"  =>  "large_card_7.jpg",
      "card8"  =>  "large_card_8.jpg",
      "card9"  =>  "large_card_9.jpg");

my $cardToUse = $availableCards{$card};
my $emailContent = "";

$text = $message;
@lines = split(/\n/, $text);
$lCnt .= $#lines+1;
$lineStart = 80;
$lineHeight = 24;



$container = "..../root-wwwin/htdocs".$cardToUse;
$font = "....verdana.ttf";




$image = GD::Image->newFromJpeg($container);


 $txtColor = $image->colorResolve(0,0,0);

 for ($i=0; $i<$lCnt; ++$i){
$xPos = 375;
$yPos = $lineStart + ($lineHeight*$i);
@bounds = $image->stringTTF($txtColor,$font,13,0,$xPos,$yPos,@lines[$i]);
}


$ts = time();
$imgFile = "ecard_".$user."_".$ts.".jpeg";

open(IMGFILE, "...$imgFile");
binmode IMGFILE;
print IMGFILE $image->jpeg;
close (IMGFILE);

$img = "<img border=0 src=\"...$imgFile\" />";

$emailContent = <<HTML;


$card


HTML


&CommonSubs::sendEmail("$to\@xxx.com","$from\@xxx.com","$cc\@xxx.com",       "","$bcc\@xxx.com",$emailContent);

print "Content-type: text/html\n\n";
print "$img";
print "ecard sent";
```

What I need is perl cgi code to make the text wrap on top of the image which is being uses as a background in the html, when it is sent via sendmail.

Thanks in advance for your help.

Comment: You probably should separate your question into 2 separate ones. You will get better answers.

Answer (score 1):

**Pre-wrap alternatives** :

```
.wordwrap {  
     white-space: pre-wrap;       /* css-3 should we be so lucky... */
     white-space: -moz-pre-wrap;  /* Mozilla, since 1999 */
     white-space: -pre-wrap;      /* Opera 4-6 ?? */
     white-space: -o-pre-wrap;    /* Opera 7 ?? */
     word-wrap: break-word;       /* Internet Explorer 5.5+ */
     _white-space: pre;   /* IE only hack to re-specify in addition to
    word-wrap  */
     }
```

Comment: Thanks for your response. This works in Firefox but not IE. The div will not show a new line or carriage return when you hit enter in the textarea box.

Comment: @seeker7805: which version of IE are you using?

Comment: Hi Nikhill:

I am using IE 8.

Regards,
seeker7805

Comment: @seeker7805: try to look at this link http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc304082(VS.85).aspx, will be helpful for you.

Answer (score 0):

For your CSS issue, try the following style:

```
.wordwrap {  
   white-space: pre-wrap;       
   word-wrap: break-word;       
   _white-space: pre;  
 }
```

Yes, the underscore is there for a reason.